# wpf progressbar.RenderTransform outside of window in designer

Tags: c#, wpf

when I apply the 180 degree transform to the progress bar it goes outside of the window. here is what it looks like in the designer. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUQYH.jpg

[image]

how can I get it to move inside the window.

here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="game.Player2Screen"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Player2Screen" Height="298" Width="310">

        <ProgressBar Name="ProgressBarTimer" Orientation="Vertical" Foreground="Blue" Background="Black" MouseLeftButtonDown="ProgressBarTimer_MouseLeftButtonDown"
Value="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Maximum="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="250" Width="265" >
            <ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
            </ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
        </ProgressBar>    
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the render transform origin.

See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754079%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to use a `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTransform`.

The way WPF handles drawing components is:

1. LayoutTransform
2. Measure
3. Arrange
4. RenderTransform
5. Render

It sounds like you want to do your transformation before measuring and arranging the component, not after.